# Runing a program appears to not work

Tags: command-line, compiling, g++

I do not know what the problem is or what happened but when I want to run a program compiled with g++ not working.

I starts like this:

```
gabi@gabi-work:~/Desktop/comp$ ./a.out
```

and receive this:

```
1gabi@gabi-work:~/Desktop/comp$
```

the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not an error. The script runs and give the output which is "1".  It is added to the same line the Terminal sees, and not making a new line after output through, so it seems like it isn't running.

All you have to do is to add a new line character which is mostly the `\n` at the end of the output so that you print a new line to the end of the output, so you don't have this behavior.

Comment: And someone forget to include an "enter" if they wanted the prompt on a newline ;)

Comment: How can I include that "enter"?

Comment: add new line character \n or whatever other characters depending on your programming language

Comment: `\n` for a newline character.

Comment: @Maythux bah, edit collisions sorry about the mess... phone editor is evil compared to main site on a computer

Comment: @ThomasW. nevermind, it's even better with your edits, thanks

Comment: @Maythux Cool.  You're welcome.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank you friend I appreciate your help